# Compare dates between rows from the same input file based on ID and replicate rows by increment date till the last working date using SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to duplicate rows by comparing the date of the current row with date of the next row for a user ID and row should be duplicated by incrementing the date where < date of the next row.

The last row of the id should increment till the lastworkingdate. If the lastworkingdate is null, should increment the date till current date.

Input:

[image]

Output expected

[image]

Please suggest if we can implement this logic using SQL Server.

I have tried the below code

```
WITH cte (User_ID, Start_DateMonth, Start_DateDAY, Last_working_date_text, lead_start_datemonth) AS
    (SELECT User_ID,
            CONVERT(date, CAST(Start_DateMonth AS varchar(50)) + '01') AS Start_DateMonth,
            Start_DateDAY,
            Last_working_date_text,
            LEAD(CONVERT(datetime, CAST(Start_DateMonth AS varchar(MAX)) + '01')) OVER (PARTITION BY User_ID
                                                                                        ORDER BY CONVERT(date, CAST(Start_DateMonth AS varchar(50)) + '01')) AS lead_start_datemonth
     FROM [dbo].[Historic_Headcount3] --mytable

     UNION ALL
     SELECT User_ID,
            CONVERT(date, DATEADD(MONTH, 1, ISNULL(Start_DateMonth, GETDATE()))),
            Start_DateDAY,
            Last_working_date_text,
            CONVERT(datetime, CAST(lead_start_datemonth AS varchar(MAX)) + '01') AS lead_start_datemonth
     FROM cte
     WHERE DATEADD(MONTH, 1, Start_DateMonth) < ISNULL(lead_start_datemonth,
                                                       CASE
                                                            WHEN ISDATE(Last_working_date_text) = 1
                                                             AND Last_working_date_text != '#' THEN CONVERT(date, Last_working_date_text)
                                                            ELSE GETDATE()
                                                       END))
SELECT User_ID,
       Start_DateMonth,
       Start_DateDAY,
       Last_working_date_text
FROM cte
ORDER BY User_ID,
         Start_DateMonth;
```

I am getting error

> The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

Comment: What have you tried so far, why didn't it work? Sample data is best supply as tabular formatted `text` or DDL and DML statements as well; please don't expect the users here to transcribe your image. Thanks.

Comment: pls check the below answer. I have updated my code here

Comment: You need to [edit] your question. Answers are for answering questions.

Comment: please check the updated question

Comment: I would look at the expression `CAST(Start_DateMonth AS varchar(MAX)) + '01')`. Also, why do you need 2GB to store the value of a date?. Without consumable sample data, there's little more I can offer as I can't test anything.

Comment: *Also, why do you need 2GB to store the value of a date?*  <-- By this they mean using `MAX` data types for small values is not a great idea.  Assuming your data is consistent with your examples, `varchar(8)` would be sufficient.

Comment: thank you for checking my issue. The issue is fixed now. I will update the working code here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This script will hopefully give you enough understanding of how to utilise a numbers table to increment your months, so that you can apply it once you get your data cleaning and transformation working as required:

```
-- Define test data
declare @t table(UserID int, StartDate date, EndDate date);
insert into @t values(1,'20190901','20200217'),(2,'20200202','20200205'),(3,'20200108',null);

-- Find maximum possible number of Month interations required
declare @Months int = (select datediff(month,min(StartDate),getdate())+1 from @t);

-- Query the data
with t(t) as(select t from (values(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) t(t))                        -- Create a table with 10 rows in
    ,n(n) as(select top(@Months) row_number() over (order by (select null))-1 from t t1,t t2,t t3,t t4) -- Cross Join the table to itself to return a row_number() up to a possible 10*10*10*10 = 10,000 rows.  Use TOP to limit this to what is actually required.
select t.UserID
      ,dateadd(month,n.n,t.StartDate) as StartDateMonth
      ,isnull(t.EndDate,getdate()) as EndDate
from @t as t
    join n
        on dateadd(month,n.n,t.StartDate) <= isnull(t.EndDate,getdate())                                -- JOIN the dates to the row_number, incrementing the months as required
order by UserID
        ,StartDateMonth;
```

Output:

```
+--------+----------------+------------+
| UserID | StartDateMonth |  EndDate   |
+--------+----------------+------------+
|      1 | 2019-09-01     | 2020-02-17 |
|      1 | 2019-10-01     | 2020-02-17 |
|      1 | 2019-11-01     | 2020-02-17 |
|      1 | 2019-12-01     | 2020-02-17 |
|      1 | 2020-01-01     | 2020-02-17 |
|      1 | 2020-02-01     | 2020-02-17 |
|      2 | 2020-02-02     | 2020-02-05 |
|      3 | 2020-01-08     | 2020-02-26 |
|      3 | 2020-02-08     | 2020-02-26 |
+--------+----------------+------------+
```

Comment: thank you for providing this code . I will check this.

Comment: I made some changes in my code and it worked. will update the code here

Answer (score 0):

The  code worked for me

with cte ([CountryId],[Is_EO_EmployeeId],[DepartmentId],[FunctionId],[Employee_StatusId],[Event_ReasonId],User_ID, Start_DateMonth, Start_DateDAY, Last_working_date_text, lead_start_datemonth) as (
    SELECT [CountryId],[Is_EO_EmployeeId],[DepartmentId],[FunctionId],[Employee_StatusId],[Event_ReasonId], User_ID, Start_DateMonth,Start_DateDAY,Last_working_date_text, CASE WHEN lead_start_datemonth IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE Convert(datetime, CAST(lead_start_datemonth AS Nvarchar(max))+'01')END AS lead_start_datemonth FROM  (
    select 
       [CountryId],
       [Is_EO_EmployeeId],
       [DepartmentId],
       [FunctionId],
       [Employee_StatusId],
       [Event_ReasonId],
        User_ID, 
        CONVERT(datetime, CAST(Start_DateMonth AS varchar(50)) + '01') AS Start_DateMonth, 
        Start_DateDAY, 
        Last_working_date_text,
        lead(Start_DateMonth) over(partition by User_ID order by CONVERT(datetime, CAST(Start_DateMonth AS varchar(50)) + '01')) lead_start_datemonth
    from [dbo].[Historic_Headcount3]) T--mytable
    union all
    select 
    [CountryId],
    [Is_EO_EmployeeId],
    [DepartmentId],
    [FunctionId],
    [Employee_StatusId],
    [Event_ReasonId],
        User_ID,
        Convert(datetime,DateAdd(month,1, ISNULL(Start_DateMonth,GetDate()))),
        Start_DateDAY,
        Last_working_date_text,
        lead_start_datemonth
    from cte
    where DateAdd(month,1, Start_DateMonth) < ISNULL(lead_start_datemonth,CASE WHEN ISDATE(Last_working_date_text)=1 AND Last_working_date_text != '#' THEN  CONVERT(datetime,Last_working_date_text) ELSE GETDATE() END)
)
select [CountryId],[Is_EO_EmployeeId],[DepartmentId],[FunctionId],[Employee_StatusId],[Event_ReasonId],User_ID, LEFT(CONVERT(varchar, Start_DateMonth,112),6) AS Start_DateMonth, Start_DateDAY ,Last_working_date_text from cte order by User_ID, Start_DateMonth OPTion (maxrecursion 0)